# How to switch an ongoing Twilio phone call to a <Pay> connector

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I would like to use the [< Pay>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pay) connector optionally while in an ongoing phone call.  I cannot find out how to do trigger a new resource during an ongoing phone call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify an "in progress" call by passing new TwiML (XML) to execute which could contain your `"<Pay>"`.

You must provide

- the ID of the call you want to modify (the "CallSid" `"CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38"`)
- and an URL where Twilio will find the instructions (the "Url" `"http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"`)

I don't know what language you're using but in PHP with Twilio's library the code would look someting like this:

```php
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid    = "ACc0966dd96e4d55d26ae72df4d6dc3494";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls("CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38")
               ->update(array(
                            "method" => "POST",
                            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
                        )
               );

print($call->to);
```

You can read more about this here
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress).